# MYSQLQuery- How to create a query where we have to list out customers who have bought a specific number of album by the same singer

Tags: mysql, sql

We have the following tables:

```
Customer:
customer_id (pk)
customer_name
customer_dob
adress
gender
```

---

```
Album:
Album_id (PK)
album_name
singer_id (FK)
```

---

```
Order_Details:
order_id (Pk)
quantity purchased
customer_id (fk)
```

---

```
Order_Basket:
Order_id (fk)
album_id (fk)
```

I want to create an SQL query statement where I want to list out customers that have purchased 4 or more albums by the same singer. I'm very new to this and I would like to seek input from the much more professional individuals here.

Comment: My input is to do one thing at a time.  Start by finding something simple, like finding the customers and the number of albums they have bought.  Then start adding stuff until you get your answer.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select customer.customer_id, album.singer_id , count(*)
from customer ,order_details, order_basket, album
where customer.customer_id = order_details.customer_id
and order_details.order_id = order_basket.order_id 
and order_basket.album_id = album.Album_id 
group by customer.customer_id, album.singer_id 
having count(*) > 3
```

Comment: this is almost what i wanted but i need to list them down without having to type any input of the singer. for instance the list needs to be showing who bought 4 or more albums constituting of the same singer:)

Comment: Using joins like that in the FROM statement is normally frowned upon. You should explicitly define your joins.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH PurchaseSummary AS (
  SELECT d.customer_id, a.singer_id, count(a.album_id) AS album_count
  FROM Order_Details d
  LEFT JOIN Order_Basket b ON on b.Order_id = d.Order_id
  LEFT JOIN Album a ON a.Album_id = b.album_id
  GROUP BY d.customer_id, a.singer_id)
SELECT ps.customer_id, ps.singer_id, ps.album_count
FROM PurchaseSummary ps
LEFT JOIN Customer c ON c.customer_id = ps.customer_id
WHERE ps.album_count >= 4
ORDER BY d.customer_id
```

Use a subquery to look at all of your orders. Because an order may have more than one album, tack on the order_basket table. Now you have all orders with albums. Tack on the Album table and you have the artist name for each of the orders. Because you also have the customer ID, you can group the customer ID and singer ID with a count of the albums. The result will be like:

```
Customer|Artist|Num Albums
1        A      1
1        B      4
2        A      1
2        B      6
2        C      5
```

Then, you select your customer ID and artist ID from that table with your condition they have to have bought >=4 albums from that artist. Lastly, join the Customer table on to get further details about that customer. If you have an Artist table too, you can join that on the Artist ID to get things like name, etc.